# PowerPointから出力したmp4動画を、VLC Media Playerで再生すると滲むのはなぜでしょうか？

Tags: mp4, powerpoint, wmv

## 問題点

PowerPointから出力したmp4の動画をVLC Media Playerで再生したところ、以下のように滲んで表示されました。

[出力例 (mp4)](https://github.com/yuji38kwmt/sandbox/blob/master/20200926-powerpoint-movie/original-480p.mp4?raw=true)

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

VLC Media Playerの設定で「ハードウエァアクセラレーション」を「自動」から「無効」に変更したら、滲まず再生できました。
他のPlayerで再生したり、他の動画で検証した結果は以下の通りです。

[Qiita に自身で投稿した同様の内容](https://qiita.com/yuji38kwmt/items/5a3dd59afbdbb218ddac) から引用

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

## 質問

再生時に滲む理由、滲まない理由を教えていただきたいです。

- VLC Media Playerの設定で「ハードウエァアクセラレーション」を無効にしたら、滲まない理由
- VLC Media Playerの設定で「ハードウエァアクセラレーション」が自動の状態で、mp4は滲み、wmvは滲まない理由
- VLC Media Playerの設定で「ハードウエァアクセラレーション」が自動の状態で、wmvからmp4に変換した動画は滲まない理由

bit rateが関係しているのでしょうか？

## 環境

- PowerPoint(Microsoft365 16.0.13127.20502 64bit)
- VLC Media Player 3.0.11
- Windows 10
- dxdiagの情報

```
---------------
Display Devices
---------------

           Card name: Intel(R) UHD Graphics 630
        Manufacturer: Intel Corporation
           Chip type: Intel(R) UHD Graphics Family
            DAC type: Internal
         Device Type: Full Device (POST)
      Display Memory: 16379 MB
    Dedicated Memory: 128 MB
       Shared Memory: 16251 MB
      Driver Version: 26.20.100.7985


---------------
Render
---------------
           Card name: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050 Ti with Max-Q Design
        Manufacturer: NVIDIA
           Chip type: GeForce GTX 1050 Ti with Max-Q Design
            DAC type: Integrated RAMDAC
         Device Type: Render-Only Device
      Display Memory: 20272 MB
    Dedicated Memory: 4021 MB
       Shared Memory: 16251 MB
      Driver Version: 27.21.14.5167
         DDI Version: 12
      Feature Levels: 12_1,12_0,11_1,11_0,10_1,10_0,9_3,9_2,9_1
        Driver Model: WDDM 2.6
```

**dxdiagのディスプレイタブ**
[image: dxdiagのディスプレイタブ]

**dxdiagのレンダータブ**
[image: dxdiagのレンダータブ]

Comment: 「ハードウエァアクセラレーション」が影響するのであれば「ハードウェア」（ディスプレイアダプターおよびドライバーバージョン）を明示すべきです。

Comment: dxdiagの情報を記載しました。